# Events not firing on local url, does url need to be specific?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm very new to Google Analytics, so apologies if this is a simple question.

I have a site that someone else set up Google Analytics for. I downloaded one of the HTML pages and I'm trying to trigger a page view and other events. I'm testing this by just opening the HTML file in my browser locally, but none of my events ever get to GA.

It looks like I have everything set up correctly with the js code, and I'm wondering if the events need to come from a specific url? I figured just having the Google Analytics code (UA-XXXX...) would be good enough to fire events from anywhere, but I'm thinking that might not be the case, and I can't find out any info about it anywhere.

Do I need to be triggering events from a specific url that's defined in Google Analytics? And if so, where can I see/change that, in Tag Manager?

Comment: Google analytics events can come from anywhere you like.  have a look at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en.

Comment: @ceejayoz I was told by moderators to ask you to nicely remove your close vote on this question So that i can supply an answer.  as your duplicate is in correct and doesn't address the question.